# How can I run dotnet commands in jenkins running in kubernetes?

Tags: .net, ubuntu, kubernetes, jenkins, pipeline

I have a jenkins running kubernetes on ubuntu 20.04 operating system. I want to run the dotnet publish command in the pipeline and script. Is there any way to do it?